# Build FLTK Multi-threaded (MT) project with Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fltk

I use fltk lib in my project.
My goal is to compile my project with all libraries dependencies in it (now problem is only with FLTK), so I don't need to install vcredist libraries on each machine, where I want to use it.
So I read that for this I need to compile my project with parameters **c/c++ --> code generation --> Runtime library --> Multi-threaded**.

Now I'm using Multi-threaded DLL and everything works fine, but when I change it to MT I get error list (they got all similar code LNK2001):

Code LNK2001 Description unresolved external symbol __imp___wgetcwd file ConsoleApplication2\fltk.lib(fl_utf8.obj)

What I should do to compile my project with MT setup?

Comment: Could you please provide a code example? This can mean 5 million different things. Error tells you that this is definitely a _linker_ error, and that you probably tried to use something that wasn't declared properly. The question is what.

Comment: The `__imp__` prefix hints at something still trying to import from a DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

My solution was recompiling FLTK static library with MT setup.